# How to close roll over mega menu with a close button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My meganav covers the entire screen on desktop and I need to allow the user to close the menu with a close button. I need to remove an over state from the parent li which does not have an ID. I'm targeting the element with the ClassName but I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`. The inspector tells me the HTML Collection contains all of the classes for the element.

Here is the li I'm trying to target in it's over state:

```
<li class="menu-6327 menuparent  menu-path-node-234366 first odd over">
    <a href="/main/academic-programs" title="">Programs</a>
        <ul class="sf-hidden" style="">
```

Here is the javascript I'm trying to use:

```
function closeMeganav() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-671");
  element.classList.remove("over");
}
```

Any thoughts on what I have wrong here or a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that `getElementsByClassName()` [returns a collection of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Syntax), rather than a single element.

You're currently treating the result of `getElementsByClassName()` as a single element:

```
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-671");
  /* element is a HTMLCollection and has not concept of a classList */
  /* element.classList.remove("over"); */
```

Instead, consider using the `querySelector()` method. This lets you select  the first element that matches the specified CSS selector (which in your case would be `.menu-671`):

```
function closeMeganav() {

  /* Prefix with . to select elements with menu-671 class */
  var element = document.querySelector(".menu-671");

  if(element) {
     /* If an element matches .menu-671 */
     element.classList.remove("over");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a period in the selector. It should be `document.querySelector(".menu-671")`

Comment: Just fixed that in prior edit - thanks for the spotting that though

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of nodes. To remove the class from the first element use `element[0]`

```
function closeMeganav() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-671");
  element[0].classList.remove("over");
}
```